# foreach directory, check condition then run piped bash commands

Tags: bash, foreach, makefile, pipe

Hello people of the internet,

Firstly I must apologize as I am relatively new to makefiles, so I may be doing this in a very unorthodox way.

I am trying to create a makefile that will
-loop through each subdirectory of a specified directory
-check the directory is the specified directory or one of the subdirectories
-run the directory's through tree and then generate an image of the tree using convert with the filepath removed.

At this point, I'm getting absolutely lost and have no idea where these issues are coming from. The whole idea is to make this code project agnostic. I have a hard coded version that works fine with all of the directories and subdirectories specified manually.

I have tried two methods so far.

**Method 1**

```
PROJECT_DIR = ../hub/hub/  
SUB_DIRECTORIES = $(shell find $(PROJECT_DIR) -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo {} \;)  
SUB_DIRECTORIES_FORMATTED = $(SUB_DIRECTORIES) | sed 's|..\/hub\/hub\/||g' | sed 's/\s\+/|/g'  

all:  
    @echo $(SUB_DIRECTORIES)  
    for $(directory) in $(SUB_DIRECTORIES); do \  
        if test $$directory = $(PROJECT_DIR); then \  
            echo "Generating root.png" && tree -P '*.py' -I '__pycache__|.c' $(directory) | convert -size 364x422 label:@- ./source/root.png; \
        else \
            "Generating $(subst $(PROJECT_DIR),,$(directory)) png" && tree -P '*.py' -I '__pycache__|.c' $(directory) | convert -size 364x422 label:@- ./source/$(subst $(PROJECT_DIR),,$(directory)).png; \
        fi \
    done
```

With this method, the subst isn't working thus resulting in these errors:
[Method 1 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWVQA.png)

**Method 2**

```
PROJECT_DIR = ../hub/hub/
SUB_DIRECTORIES =: $(shell find $(PROJECT_DIR) -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo {} \;)
SUB_DIRECTORIES_FORMATTED = $(SUB_DIRECTORIES) | sed 's|..\/hub\/hub\/||g' | sed 's/\s\+/|/g'

all:  
    @$(foreach file, $(wildcard $(SUB_DIRECTORIES)/), \  
        $(if $(filter $(file), $(PROJECT_DIR)), \  
            $(shell tree -P '*.py' -I '__pycache__|.c' $(file) | convert -size 364x422 label:@- ./source/root.png;), \  
            $(shell tree -P '*.py' -I '__pycache__|.c' $(file) | convert -size 364x422 label:@- ./source/$(subst $(PROJECT_DIR),,$(file)).png;) \  
        ) \  
    );
```

This method causes another error: [method 2 errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmukO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When you post a Question, you should include necessary information such as the text of error messages; not link, not a screenshot, but the actual text. Also, when you write a makefile (or any code), it is best not to try to do too many new things at once. I will take a crack at this, but you have not made it easy...

Comment: ...All right, I have a partial answer: you are getting your *Make* variables and your *shell* variables mixed up. I suggest you try something simpler: iterate over the list of directories, and echo the name of each one. Edit your question to show us the results (either the makefile that succeeded, or your best attempt which failed).

Comment: It sounds like you want to write a shell script.  Makefile syntax is an extremely awkward way to package that.  How about just letting your script be a script?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please fix the formatting of your post? You can see [/help/formatting](/help/formatting) and also [/editing-help](/editing-help) for help on how to do so.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue so I included the solution and fixed the formatting of the code @starball. Beta & John, the original code includes quite a few more steps and was originally done in make. I didn't think of doing it solely in bash, but now that you point it out, there's nothing being done that requires make so I will definitely switch to a shell script. This will save me many hours of banging my head against the wall for sure ! Thanks for your responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for your comments.

The issue was coming from the added "" after $(SUB_DIRECTORIES) and the semi-colon at the end. It's relieving to know that I was not far off from the solution. I was able to get it to work with **Method 2** using the following code. :

```
PROJECT_DIR = ../hub/hub/
SUB_DIRECTORIES = $(shell find $(PROJECT_DIR) -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec echo {} \;)
SUB_DIRECTORIES_FORMATTED = $(SUB_DIRECTORIES) | sed 's|..\/hub\/hub\/||g' | sed 's/\s\+/|/g'

all:
    $(foreach file, $(wildcard $(SUB_DIRECTORIES)), \
        $(if $(filter $(file), $(PROJECT_DIR)), \
            $(shell tree -P '*.py' -I '__pycache__|.c' $(file) | convert -size 1280x1024 label:@- ./source/root.png), \
            $(shell tree -P '*.py' -I '__pycache__|.c' $(file) | convert -size 1280x1024 label:@- ./source/$(subst $(PROJECT_DIR),,$(file)).png) \
        ) \
    )
```